# safetensors issue with Huggingface embeddings

Tags: python, jupyter, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, sentence-transformers

Running into the following:

local Win10 Anaconda Setup in jupyter notebook.

`!pip install safetensors Requirement already satisfied: safetensors in ...\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages (0.3.1)`

Installed safetensors
Trying to load Huggingface embeddings:

```
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
```

Getting this error constantly. Anyone has an idea?

```
Failed to import transformers.models.mpnet.modeling_mpnet because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):%0D%0ANo module named 'safetensors._safetensors_rust'
```

Already tried to install rust compiler, installed from wheel, all with same problem.
Tried the same notebook in google colab and it worked without any issues.

Comment: Try `conda install -U accelerate transformers langchain` and `conda install -c conda-forge tokenizers`